# NSURLRequest hanging SpringBoard

Tags: objective-c, jailbreak, nsurlrequest, springboard

I have a MobileSubstrate addon that hooks springboard (not in the actual objective c code, but with the plist). It contains a UIWebView, which loads a NSURLRequest. This NSURLRequest is here:

```
NSString *urlAddress = @"http://www.google.com";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

This NSURLRequest hangs springboard. I did LOTS of testing, and I am 100% sure that this NSURLRequest hangs springboard, and not any other element of the MobileSubstrate Tweak.

I await your advice and/or solutions.

UPDATE:
I'm going to try threading the loading of the page. If that doesn't work, I'll report back.

Comment: It's obviously your substrate addon.  Your code is fine.  Maybe you should post the addon.

Comment: Putting this on a background thread is not an option - it's UIKit stuff - and unnecessary because UIWebView will perform what it can in the background and in a non-blocking fashion (although it's not always great at doing that).  If you really want to prove to yourself that this code is correct, then put it in a sample project without your MobileSubstrate Tweak and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not your code, it's using UIWebView in SpringBoard. SpringBoard somehow doesn't react well to doing that. Same with using system(). 
It's a known problem, but afaik there has been no solution yet.